# Most efficient method of performing &&?

Tags: java, flash, boolean, overhead, performance

I've got a common situation where you have two variables (xSpeed and ySpeed) which I want to independently set to zero when they fall below minSpeed, and exit when they're both zero.

What would be the most efficient method? Currently I have two methods (Method 2 being cleaner), but I was wondering if you guys knew a better way....

`Method1:`

```
bool isZeroX = Math.abs(xSpeed)< minSpeed;
bool isZeroY = Math.abs(ySpeed)< minSpeed;

if(isZeroX && isZeroY) return -1;
else if(isZeroX) xSpeed = 0;
else if(isZeroY) ySpeed = 0;
```

`Method2:`

```
if(Math.abs(xSpeed)< minSpeed) xSpeed = 0;
if(Math.abs(ySpeed)< minSpeed) ySpeed = 0;
if(ySpeed==0 && xSpeed==0) return -1;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
if(-minSpread < xSpeed && xSpeed < minSpeed) {
    xSpeed = 0;
    if(-minSpread < ySpeed && ySpeed < minSpeed) {
        ySpeed = 0;
        return -1;
    }
} else if(-minSpread < ySpeed && ySpeed < minSpeed) {
    ySpeed = 0;
}
```

Comment: of course! genius! But why do I need -minSpread. Is using Math.abs that slow?

Comment: `Math.abs(int)` can result in a branch which is the most expensive part of this code.  Overall it cuts down the number of branches.  You can combine `-minSpread < xSpeed && xSpeed < minSpeed` into a single comparison, but it makes the code almost unreadable for very little performance difference.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer your second example because it is the most readable. Prefer readability over efficiency unless you can prove that you should be optimising.

Comment: hey thanks - but its a small app so Im going to be the only one reading the code. As long as I myself understand it, efficiency should take priority.

Comment: Disagree.  Even on projects that only you are working on, it's properly the JIT's job to do this level of microoptimization.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I agree. "I understand it" should be "I understand it easily, after 6 months of not thinking about it at all".

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps make an elegant boolean method to see if the object is moving/stopped:

```
boolean isStopped() {
    if(Math.abs(xSpeed)< minSpeed) xSpeed = 0;
    if(Math.abs(ySpeed)< minSpeed) ySpeed = 0;

    return (ySpeed==0 && xSpeed==0);
}
```